# Question regarding post decrement in loop jointed with if

Tags: java, if-statement, decrement

What is the difference between the following to code? The result is different. `b` is some `String` and `int j = b.length() - 1`

The `if` branch is in a loop and runs many times if this makes any difference.

```
if (j >=0 && b.charAt(j) == '1') {
    j--;
    carry ++;
}
```

vs.

```
if (j >=0 && b.charAt(j--) == '1') {
    carry ++;
}
```

Comment: They are both the same and should produce the same result.

Comment: Please post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The first one does not alter `j` if the condition `b.charAt(j) == '1'` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if the 1st condition is true and the 2nd condition is false?

```
//   true              false
//    V                  V
if (j >=0 && b.charAt(j) == '1') foo();   // foo not executed, j not changed

//    V                  V
if (j >=0 && b.charAt(j--) == '1') foo(); // foo not executed, j decremented
```